# Flash notice text in dark theme turns light, while its background is still light

Tags: bug, dark-mode

This flash notice showed up in my session and I could barely see the text, because it was a very light grey. I'm not sure if there's a way to report bugs on this website, so I brought it here. Who can I inform of this?

(I accidentally didn't get the screenshot of the light text, sorry. This is what it looks like when I use the light theme)

[image]

Comment: Please read/search the answers on the linked question to see if there is a an answer which mentions the same issue. I believe there is. If not, add an answer on that question.